# Error while passing bytes20 to contract using ionic

Tags: blockchain, dapps

While I am trying to run a dapp in ionic using angular, not able to pass bytes20 values to ethereum smart contract. Below showing code and corresponding error:

app.js

```
smartcontract.deployed().then(function(instance){
    instance.save(usid,{from :account,gas:400000});
})
```

SmartContract.sol

```
bytes20 arr =[];
function save(bytes20 usid)public {
    arr.push(usid);
}
```

Error comes :

```
Error: invalid bytes20 value (arg="usid", coderType="bytes20", value="U345546")
at Object.throwError (errors.js:68)
at CoderFixedBytes.encode (abi-coder.js:433)
at abi-coder.js:605
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at pack (abi-coder.js:604)
at CoderTuple.encode (abi-coder.js:764)
at AbiCoder.encode (abi-coder.js:897)
at ABICoder.encodeParameters (index.js:96)
at index.js:426
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Environment:

```
OS      : Ubuntu 18.04
Ionic   : 4 
Cordova : 9
truffle : 4.1.5
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `usid` value and type? Can you try using [`web3.utils.toHex(<value>)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#tohex) to pass the value as a hexadecimal string?

Comment: "usid" is user's id (for example 'USR43564654') and its type is byte20.

Comment: It seems you are using truffle-contract which is based on web3.js and it doesn't know anything about ionic's bytes20 type.